# So strtok is destructive?

Tags: c, strtok

Do I understand correctly that `strtok` leaves the source string larded with null characters?

I could understand that each new iteration call first replaces the null-character it put there with the original character and then continues, and that the last call, which returns null because there are no more marches, then replaces the last null character it last put there with its original. As a result, the source string would end-up unmodified. (Of course, would you stop before this last call, the source string will remain modified.)

But no documentation mentions such a strategy. So I must first copy the source string to another buffer before processing with `strtok` if I want the source string to remain unmodified?

Comment: Interesting. AFAIK it is a well-known effect but documentation such as its [online `man` page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) lists it under ***Bugs***: "These functions modify their first argument."

Comment: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.21.5.8p2

Comment: @usr2564301 do not believe in everyrhing you see in the `man` pagesd

Comment: @usr2564301 bug ? so *scanf* family function are also bugged etc

Comment: Paul: do note that your suggested strategy still *modifies* the string. A better implementation would also run on read-only strings. It'd probably be slower, but not by much. (Ah wait – then it needs persistent storage for the next extracted `*token`. So no *compatible* replacement is possible.)

Comment: Seems I will have to write my own "cunning" implementation of `strtok` (and make sure I call it until null is returned). Thanks you all for your feedback.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie there is no other way if want to parse the string. I do not think that anyone uses it in the production code.

Comment: Patching after tokenising is problematic if you want more than the last token, e.g. when you save the tokens in an array. "Views" into the original string that store the start pointer and the length of the token could be useful, except that you won't have null-terminated strings anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [C standard explicitly states](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.8p2) "**breaks** the string ... into...":

> A sequence of calls to the strtok function breaks the string pointed to by `s1` into a sequence of tokens

Explicitly breaking "the string pointed to by `s1`" more than implies the original string is modified.

[Note also the synopsis](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.8p1):

**Synopsis**

```
     #include <string.h>
     char *strtok(char * restrict s1,
          const char * restrict s2);
```

It's `char * restrict s1`, tellingly lacking any `const`.

Note that it's the "sequence of calls" that "breaks" the string.  Restoring the string after each token is parsed would not comply with the requirement to "break the string", or that the string be "broken" after the "sequence of calls".

[POSIX makes the modification explicit](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) (bolding mine):

> The `strtok()` function then searches from there for a byte that is contained in the current separator string. If no such byte is found, the current token extends to the end of the string pointed to by `s`, and subsequent searches for a token shall return a null pointer. **If such a byte is found, it is overwritten by a NUL character, which terminates the current token**. The `strtok()` function saves a pointer to the following byte, from which the next search for a token shall start.

Comment: Yes, I know that. It is in the documentation. M. Oehm gave a valid point why it is as it is (or why it cannot be changed anymore as it is).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I just added that restoring the string would not be compliant with the "breaking" of the string.  After such a parsing, the restored string would not be "broken".  Why it was first implemented that way is probably to allow access to the tokens post-parsing, and any other standardization would have likely broken existing code.

Comment: It is such a pity that quotes from the Standards no longer stand out with a light-yellow background. The questionable *improvement* was discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343919/some-improvements-to-blockquotes). If you have a workaround, you can answer [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394644/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-contrast-for-blockquotes-such-as-the-old-style-w)

Answer (score 3):

`strtok` is destructive and it is described in the standard

> If such  a  character  is  found,  it  is  overwritten  by  a  null 
>   character,which terminates  the  current  token.

[image]

7.21.5.8

Comment: Yes, I know that. It is in the documentation. So it definitely destroys the source and no "cunning scheme" restores it.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie how do you imagine the restoring algorithm?

Comment: The [note here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok#Note) also points out this behavior with the word _destructive_, and you can cite _"If such character was found, it is replaced by the null character `'\0'` and the pointer to the following character is stored in a static location for subsequent invocations."_ with a link instead of a screenshot...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts cpprefderence has more bugs than windows vista alpha verison. And for sure is not something to link as source of knowledge

Comment: @P__J__ The first I've heard such an opinion... most professional C and C++ developers I've encountered recommend cppreference as the best available reference documentation, particularly in comparison to cplusplus and MSDN, which are typically higher ranked in google search results. Is your evidence of these bugs merely anecdotal, or is there some sort of meta question or forum in which this opinion is widely held?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts the only source of the 100% correct information is the **Standard** and if you look for the implementation specific information the **compiler documentation**. MSDN is a windows and microsoft compiler -centric. Very useful if you work on windows app or driver. Other sites can be used as a **quick** reference if you forget something like the parameters order or types. Not to discuss the details

Comment: @P__J__ that's a fair point. It makes more sense to cite the standard in this case here, it's _by definition_ the "source of knowledge" as you say. I was just wondering why I haven't heard your opinion before of cppreference being a bad source of reference documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> So strtok is destructive?

Yes.

> So I must first copy the source string to another buffer before processing with strtok if I want the source string to remain unmodified?

Copying is one way.

**Alternative**

Another is to seek the start and length of the token.  Then no need to modify the source string.

The pointer returned is not a string of the token, just its beginning.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Return beginning of token.
const char *my_strtok(const char *s, const char *delim, size_t *token_length) {
  // Skip over leading delimiters
  const char *token = s + strspn(s, delim);
  *token_length = strcspn(token, delim);
  if (*token_length == 0) {
    // No token was found
    return NULL;
  }
  return token;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  const char *s = "Jenny:867-5309";  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/867-5309/Jenny
  size_t length;
  while ((s = my_strtok(s, "-:", &length)) != NULL) {
    printf("<%.*s>\n", (int) length, s);  // print only to the length of the token.
    s += length;
  }
}
```

Output

```
<Jenny>
<867>
<5309>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, `strtok()` can modify its first string argument, and I love your description: *`strtok` leaves the source string larded with null characters*.

Your proposed strategy is interesting and not difficult to implement, but it is incompatible with the current semantics as defined by the C Standard. The description is very precise as to where null bytes are set in the source string. Note also that your proposal still has two shortcomings:

- it uses a hidden static state.
- it modifies the argument string, thus is inadequate for string constants.
- every subsequent call modifies the *tokens* returned by the previous calls as the null terminators are progressively replaced by the original bytes. This behavior would be even more counter-intuitive than the current side effects.

To perform the same parsing tasks as `strtok()` without modifications to the source string, I suggest you use these often overlooked but standard string functions from `<string.h>`:

```
// return the number of characters at the start of s1 not matching any characters from s2
size_t strcspn(const char *s1, const char *s2);

// return the number of characters at the start of s1 matching one of the characters in s2
size_t strspn(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

For example, here is a simple function that breaks its string argument into words separated by whitespace or punctuation:

```c
void print_words(const char *str) {
    const char *separators = " \t\r\n,.:;'-";
    int len;
    for (;;) {
        /* skip separators */
        str += strspn(str, separators);
        if (*str == '\0')
            break;
        /* get the word length */
        len = strcspn(str, separators);
        /* output the word */
        printf("%.*s\n", len, str);
        /* skip the word */
        str += len;
    }
}
```